# Are there any examples of semantics non-preserving optimizations (except FP optimizations)?

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, semantics

It is considered that optimizations have semantics preservation property. However, floating-point (FP) optimizations may not preserve the semantics. Usually these FP-optimizations are the result of selection of non-strict FP models (examples: [ICC](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compiler-option-details/floating-point-options/fp-model-fp.html), [MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fp-specify-floating-point-behavior?view=msvc-170), [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath), [Clang/LLVM](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-floating-point-behavior),  [KEIL](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armclang_ref/armclang_ref_rni1489589347476.htm), etc.).

Out of curiosity, are there any examples of other semantics non-preserving optimizations?

Comment: Of course many optimizations break things that only happened to work in debug mode, i.e. de-facto semantics of debug mode.  Because those things are actually undefined behaviour.  Like data-race UB between threads, or between a thread and interrupt/signal handlers in it: [MCU programming - C++ O2 optimization breaks while loop](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/387181) .  A classic example is optimization breaking overflow-detection code that causes signed-integer overflow and then checks if it happened.  (Causing UB which compilers can assume didn't happen.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are, but you have to look hard to find them.

Try replacing a standard library function. If it doesn't do what the standard library function does, you may find that your code doesn't do what you expect, because the compiler assumes standard library functions do what the documentation says they do.

Also, `mmap()` a region at address zero. The compiler may omit code that accesses it because it assumes that code is unreachable because it dereferences a NULL pointer and thus undefined behavior. However, if that `mmap()` call succeeds, the behavior of dereferencing a zero (NULL is zero on most platforms) just became defined. `gcc` has a compiler option to tell it to stop doing that. Clang eventually caved to pressure to add it because it would otherwise miscompile the kernel. https://reviews.llvm.org/D47894#change-z5AkMbcq7h1h

Back in the 90s when the aliasing rules were just starting to become things, there were more examples, as the aliasing rules changed the definition of the language. But this is well-settled now.

Comment: Sounds more like implementation bugs.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The null pointer thing between lknl and clang went on for years each calling the other side bugged.

Comment: Also I am not sure what the standard says about reimplementing standard functions with ones having different semantics than the standard defines.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: For GCC at least, those functions are assumed unless you use `-fno-builtin-strchr` or whatever, to not implicitly define `strchr` as `__builtin_strchr`.  (Or `-fno-builtin` for all functions, implied by `-ffreestanding`.)  I'm not sure exactly how the C standard defines the library for freestanding implementations.

Comment: Re: "calling the other side bugged": does it mean that effects of the `-fdelete-null-pointer-checks`, `-fstrict-aliasing`, `-fstrict-overflow` are considered bugs? To my understanding the compiler assumes that the input source code is UB-free and can apply optimizations (e.g. `(x + 1) > x;` [if `x` is `int`] is replaced to `1`). Does it mean that lknl developers are unsure that the kernel code is UB-free?

Comment: @pmor: The kernel memory model provides a definition of dereferencing NULL. `-fstrict-aliasing` and `-fstrict-overflow` are in a completely different class than `-fdelete-null-pointer-checks`.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Does it mean that lknl is built using `-fstrict-aliasing` and `-fstrict-overflow`?